# Show $\mu_*$ is a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose $\mu$ is a finitely additive set function on Borel $\sigma$ algebra on $\mathbb R$ with $\mu(\mathbb R)<\infty$. Define $\mu_*(A)=\sup \{\mu(K)|K\subset A,K$ compact$\}$. Show that $\mu_*$ is a measure on Borel sets.

I cannot even show $\mu_*$ is finitely additive. More specifically, I need help in the following direction. If A,B are disjoint Borel then $\mu_*(A\cup B)\leq \mu_*(A)+\mu_*(B)$. The issue is, if I take any compact K subset of $A\cup B$ then I cannot split K to get compact sets K1 and K2 subsets of A and B respectively.

Comment: A,B are not closed. So these won’t be subsets of A,B respectively.

Comment: For example take A=(0,1),B=[1,2) and K=[1/2,3/2]

Comment: Are you familiar with Natanson I.P. - Theory of functions of a real variable? There is separate chapter about "The outer and inner measures of a bounded set"  based exactly on opened/closed set conception

Comment: No I am not, sorry.

Comment: You can found it on libgen and, possibly, you prefer to yourself read interesting for you places - it's on page 63 of 1983 year. Write, if you'll have problem and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a not-mentioned hypothesis, which I think is needed, which is that $\mu\geq0$.

Note first that $\mu$ preserves order, since for $A\setminus B$ we have
$$
\mu(A)\leq\mu(A)+\mu(B\setminus A)=\mu(A\cup(B\setminus A))=\mu(B).
$$
And $\mu$ is subadditive, since $$
\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A\cup(B\setminus A))=\mu(A)+\mu(B\setminus A)\leq\mu(A)+\mu(B). 
$$

Let $A,B$ be Borel sets and $K\subset A\cup B$ be compact. Then $A\cap K$ and $B\cap K$ are Borel sets, so
$$
\mu(K)\leq\mu((A\cap K)\cup (B\cap K))\leq\mu(A)+\mu(B). 
$$
Then $\mu_*(A\cup B)\leq\mu(A)+\mu(B)$.

If $\mu_*(A)=\infty$ or $\mu_*(B)=\infty$, the inequality holds. Otherwise, Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and choose $K_1\subset A, K_2\subset B$ compact with $\mu(A)<\mu(K_1)+\varepsilon$, $\mu(B)<\mu(K_2)+\varepsilon$. Then
$$
\mu_*(A\cup B)\leq \mu(A)+\mu(B)\leq \mu(K_1)+\mu(K_2)+2\varepsilon\leq\mu_*(A)+\mu_*(B)+2\varepsilon. 
$$
As $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, $\mu_*(A\cup B)\leq\mu_*(A)+\mu_*(B)$.

Comment: So you are $\mu$-approximating $A,B$ by compact sets $K_1,K_2$. Hmm, interesting idea. I knew this could be done for a finite measure $\mu$, but it seems you can do it for a finitely additive set function too. And yes, $\mu\geq 0$.

Comment: It's what the definition gives you. You have to use it somehow.